# Is there a way to remove the last remaining element from an array and leave this empty?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects in Javascript (I use Vue.js2 in my project) and with `.splice` I can easily delete all the elements inside of it. The problem is, when only one element remains, I can't delete it because it stays there no matter what.

Comment: Can you pop the last value?

Comment: You can definitely splice the last element, you'll need to provide more details.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: With pop it doesn't work. Wait a moment please so that I can edit my question with code

Comment: Apologize me, while editing my question I've found the error, splice works fine, I'll delete my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to clean up an array is to make it [array].length = 0

Answer (score 0):

You can use .length, .filter, .pop and im pretty sure you can .splice the last element, maybe there is something else u havent noticed yet.